# Error: "sorry this site cannot be shared with you"

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, site-collection, site

I'm using the following PowerShell script to create 15 Site collections. The problem is it only creates only two permission groups and we have to create the rest manually.

Does anyone know a script that creates all the permission groups because when we used this script earlier we create the groups manually we get "sorry this site cannot be shared with you" error.

[image]

Comment: what permission groups you are talking about? by default SharePoint create 3 groups (Site collection name Members, Owners and visitors), are these groups created?

Comment: Have you tried to go to central administration - site collections - change site collection administrators - enter your user as site collection administrator on the site and try again. Then you should have full access and be able to create groups without permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

here you have the snippet

```
#New-SPSite doesn't create default SharePoint security groups
#Create new site collection default groups and change the title to the desrired one
#as per our framework requirements
$Sitename = 'SiteName'
$siteURL = 'siteURL'
try
{
    write-host -foregroundcolor cyan $Sitename "Creating Default Association Groups......"
    $web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl;
    # this symbol i:0#.w is presenting windows authentication security mechanism
    $owner1 = $web.EnsureUser('domain\username')
    $owner2 = $web.EnsureUser('domain\username')
    $web.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups($owner1,$owner2,$siteName);
    $web.Title = 'DesiredTitle'
    $web.Update()
    write-host -foregroundcolor green $Sitename "Successfully created default association groups!"
}
catch [System.Exception]
{
    write-host $Sitename "Default association groups creation failed."
```

}